# WiFi - Limited after network change

Tags: windows-10

I recently bought a new laptop and it was working fine, but I ran into some difficulties a few weeks back. I use my laptop both at school and at home, and connect to the two different networks using my laptop, however, when I change network (from either school to home or vice versa), the laptop shows that it is connected to the network, but there is no internet connection, and remains like this until I go into device manager and disable and reenable the network card. Are there any fixes for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is an TAB within device manager for your wireless card to turn off power management. The checkbox says 'Allow this computer to turn off this device to save power' - This should be unchecked.

Another method would be to shutdown your laptop at the school then restart when you get home, rather than using sleep mode. Quite a few laptops don't wake up properly from sleep mode and this may be happening to you.

Comment: I do both of those things, but it still occurs, even after shutdown which I found weird.

Comment: Also try switching off/on the wireless adapter - Most laptops have a keyboard function to do this - If still no joy it's cheaper and quicker to switch off that wifi card/driver, and purchase a cheap USB wireless adapter.